# Ubuntu 12.04.2 recovery mode entry removal from grub

Tags: 12.04, grub2, recovery-mode

I spent an hour trying to remove the recovery mode entry off Grub, but I did not succeed!

I edited the `/etc/default/grub` and uncommented:

```
# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
```

and did the `update-grub` with no success, the entry still exists on reboot.

Also I edit and commented lines regarding the recovery mode in: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
#menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
#   recordfail
#   insmod gzio
#   insmod part_msdos
#   insmod ext2
#   set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
#   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 692988db-a701-4abb-9889-fc61816aa8d8
#   echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-23-generic ...'
#   linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=692988db-a701-4abb-9889-fc61816aa8d8 ro recovery nomodeset 
#   echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
#   initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
```

then I ran `update-grub`

I also ran `update-grub2`

...without success. After restarting, the recovery mode entry still exists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Instead of

```
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
```

and running update-grub solved the problem.